# What is prefered method to set consistence font-size and line height for website using em?

Tags: css, xhtml, typography

What is the best method to set cross-browser consistence typography (font-size and line height) for whole site using `em` for Fixed width `{Width:970px}`, centered website?

I usually get design from client with multiple font size and line heights at various places in design. for some good reason i still use `em`

without getting nested element problem and font-size inconsistencies in IE and others.

then after setting how to manage and update easily ,and how to calculate `ems`

I want to set easily manageable font sizes and I want to set Line height manually (because it can be different for various places in design.

And for which things we should define line-height or for which not?

How to set font-size and line-height to get consistent result. and if i'm using `em` for font-sizing then should i also use bottom-margin of h1, p, li etc in `em`?

```
    HTML {}

    BODY {}

    P {}

    a {}

    ul li a {}

    ul li ul li a {}

    p img {float:left}

td,th { }
```

Comment: For what it is worth (I use em mostly) I used this reset to get the browsers the same: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/01/15/resetting-again/

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss - CSS Reset alone is not a solution of every problem.

Comment: Some other information regarding em - it is a jquery plug-in but the background information is generic and relevent here: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_plugin_for_retaining_scalable_interfaces_with_pixel_to_em_con/

Comment: And another discussion here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/

Comment: but jquery would be overkill for this.

Comment: On reset: agreed, but it has helped me garner a consistent start place, which is why it is a comment and not an answer to your question at all really :)

On jQuery - yes, but the discussion there is the relevent part :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/

(thank you for putting check mark besides this answer)